# Manipulate div heights with relation to window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several divs i.e

```
<div class="div_1"></div>
<div class="div_2"></div>
<div class="div_3"></div>
```

After getting window height by

```
windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

I want to manipulate the div height to be a proportion of the window height for example div_1 should be 30%, div_2 should be 45% of window height etc. I need to do this in javascript / jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manipulated @void's answer to get an answer that I expected. The code is

```
$('.div_1').height(windowHeight*30/1400+"em");
```

I divided the windowHeight by 1400 instead 100 because the body font is 14px, for changing it from px to em.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use CSS

```
.div_1 {height:30vh;}
```

This will set height equal to 30% of the height of viewport. [`vh`](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) is the height of viewport.

It is partially supported in IE > 8 and other then that not supported in Opera, else where it is completely supported. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

To do it in jQuery

```
$('.div_1').css("height", $(document).height()*30/100+"px"); // Will set its height equal to 30% of that of document.
```

Comment: I need to do it in javascript / jquery

Comment: @LutaV check the answer, what is the problem in doing it with CSS?

Comment: I've improved your answer. check it

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative using jquery & data attribute

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="div_1" data-percent="30">Div1</div>
  <div class="div_2" data-percent="40">Div2</div>
  <div class="div_3" data-percent="30">Div3</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(window).resize(function(){
  var height = window.innerHeight;
   console.log('resised',height)
      $('#container>div').each(function(){
         $(this).height(height*parseInt($(this).data('percent'))/100);
        console.log($(this).height(),height*parseInt($(this).data('percent'))/100);
      });
    })
</script>
```